# how to make input available when signing out in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

when you sign out and then you try to sign in in laravel the inputs(username,password) are empty how to make that the inputs become fill with that username and password when you the last time that you signed in

Comment: What's the point of a username/password if you do that?!

Comment: this functionality is available of all sites including stackoverflow

Comment: can you just save the username/password with your browser?  or use some third party browser extension like lastpass?

Comment: ...I think OP is referring to the Auto-fill functionality in browsers.

Comment: "this functionality is available of all sites including stackoverflow" StackOverflow most certainly does not do this. Your browser might.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't doing that. you have saved your password in the browser and the browser is doing that.

Answer (score 6):

Although there are ways to do as you wish, this entire process is extremely insecure and I would recommend, no, insist on forgetting this and moving on.

The process of the username and password being automatically entered is something that modern browsers do, mostly. For example, Chrome will remember your username and password if you have told it to do so (It pops up as a bar at the top after signing in if it believes the information should be saved).

Setting this information in a cookie would be insecure for a few reasons, mainly, the information would be readable and could potentially be stolen from the end users machine meaning that a malicious user now has the credentials of the user logging in. Also, if the end user is using a public machine, anyone with access to that machine now has access to the users account.

We don't store passwords in the database as plain text, and that's 100 times more difficult to access compared to a cookie, so why store it in a cookie? Furthermore, an email or a username is equally as dangerous to provide as this information can be used in a variety of ways to gain access to the account or to gain other information from a user.

Let the browser or third party tool of an individual user handle this, having the machine remember them for you and re-enter them, defeats the purpose of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers provide this functionality, so there is no need to implement it in a web app, especially as it is a security risk.

The browser will offer the user the choice to store, or not, and optionally to encrypt the password store to a master password.

Answer (score -6):

You'd need to use cookies. BUT, (and all others WILL agree with me when I tell you) this is a TERRIBLE idea. You'd be echo'ing out in plain text the users password.

Leave it up to the browser the user is using to securely save their password without it being put into the easily readable by anyone at the computer AND any plugin/extension installed.

There's no way to force the browser to autofill, either.

This is how you would use cookies.

This will save the cookie forever, until it's overwritten.

`Cookie::forever('key', 'value');`

will work or set a `$minutes` var and use the following

`$minutes = 60; // save cookie for 1hr`

`Cookie::make('key', 'value', $minutes)`.

Then in your input

`<?=Cookie::get('key');?>`

I'd HIGHLY recommend looking at the Laravel documentation. It's EXTREMELY clear. As far as any documentation I've read, it's the easiest to understand.

If you use the `<?=` short tag, ensure that your short tags are enabled in your php.ini otherwise use `<?php echo`

I'm not sure if Laravel will automatically overwrite.

The problem with storing usernames in cookies, is a problem all cookies have. If you echo the cookie, you'll need to use `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` otherwise if the cookie had been modified, it could inject script into the page.